# ¿Por qué se me auto-redirecciona?

Tags: apache, debian

Tengo un sitio web el cual en cierto momento le puse en el archivo correspondiente al sitio en site-aviabled la instrucción redirect 301 (url-vieja) (url-nueva), la question es que quité ya esa orden y cuando reinicie el apache aun me sigue redireccionando, no he puesto más nada en ningun lugar, saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que esta respuesta no te va a gustar mucho: el problema no es con Apache, sino con los navegadores que estás usando y cómo manejan la caché.

Una redirección 301 es una redirección **permanente**, es decir, le estás diciendo al cliente que la página buscada se ha movido completamente y para siempre y le indicas una nueva URL donde puede encontrarla.

**Si el programa cliente guarda esa redirección en la caché, entonces hará siempre la redirección incluso si tú la borras del fichero `.htaccess`**, hasta que el cliente decida borrar la caché (fuera de tu control) y a veces ni siquiera así ([puedes leer esta historia relacionada en inglés](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/), y la rocambolesca manera en la que solucionó el problema creando multiples redirecciones).

Nota que las personas que visiten la página por primera vez, la verán correctamente; el problema lo tendrán las personas que hayan visitado la página con anterioridad y hayan recibido el código de redirección 301. Lo que quiere decir que si sólo pusiste la redirección 301 en local, sólo tú tendrás el problema, pero tus usuarios online no lo tendrán e irán a la página correcta.

Si lo que quieres es realizar una redirección temporal, deberías usar un redirect 302 (Found) en su lugar, o te puede crear problemas futuros (como los del enlace o los que estás experimentando).

Comment: Para sumar a la respuesta, una manera simple de probarlo es usar sesión privada del navegador, si no hace la redirección es que efectivamente es ese el problema.